# TypeError: this.props.myMaterials.fetch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm working on jest unit testing using `react-test-renderer`.The test cases fails and showing this error

> "TypeError: this.props.myMaterials.fetch is not a function"

where `this.props.notes.fetch` is inside the `componentWillMount`.Is there any solution to fix this without using enzyme?

myComponent.jsx :

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          column: this.getColumns(),
          pageNotFound: false
        };
      }


      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.notes.fetch(this.props.courseId);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResizeEvent);
        this.handleError = EventBus.on(constants.NOTES_NOT_FOUND, () => {
          this.setState({ pageNotFound: true });
        });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResizeEvent);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResizeEvent);
        this.handleError();
      }

      handleResizeEvent = () => {
        this.setState({ column: this.getColumns() });
      };

      getColumns = () => (window.innerWidth > (constants.NOTES_MAX_COLUMNS * constants.NOTES_WIDTH) ?
        constants.NOTES_MAX_COLUMNS :
        Math.floor(window.innerWidth / constants.NOTES_WIDTH))

      callback = (msg, data) => {
      }
      render() {
        const { notes, language } = this.props;
        if (this.state.pageNotFound) {
          return (<div className="emptyMessage"><span>Empty</span></div>);
        }
        if (notes.loading) {
          return (<Progress/>);
        }
        // To Refresh Child component will receive props
        const lists = [...notes.cards];
        return (
          <div className="notesContainer" >
            <NoteBook notesList={lists} callback={this.callback} coloums={this.state.column} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

myComponent.propTypes = {
  notes: PropTypes.object,
  courseId: PropTypes.string,
  language: PropTypes.shape(shapes.language)
};
export default withRouter(myComponent);
```

myComponent.test.jsx:

```
const tree = renderer.create(
<myComponent.WrappedComponent/>).toJSON();
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: it doesn’t look like your componentWillMount is using “this.props.myMaterials”. Where is myMaterials passed in as a prop?

Comment: Sorry,updated the codes.

Comment: What's the defaultProps that you have?

Comment: Please provide full code of the component.

Comment: Can you please provide full code?

Comment: Updated the myCompoenent.jsx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty evident from the error that while testing you are not supplying the prop `notes` which is being used in your `componentWillMount` function. Pass it when you are creating an instance for testing and it should work.

All you need to do is this

```
const notes = {
    fetch: jest.fn() 
}
const tree = renderer.create(
    <myComponent.WrappedComponent notes={notes}/>).toJSON();
     expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

One more thing that you should take care is that your component names must begin with Uppercase characters.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          column: this.getColumns(),
          pageNotFound: false
        };
      }


      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.notes.fetch(this.props.courseId);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResizeEvent);
        this.handleError = EventBus.on(constants.NOTES_NOT_FOUND, () => {
          this.setState({ pageNotFound: true });
        });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResizeEvent);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResizeEvent);
        this.handleError();
      }

      handleResizeEvent = () => {
        this.setState({ column: this.getColumns() });
      };

      getColumns = () => (window.innerWidth > (constants.NOTES_MAX_COLUMNS * constants.NOTES_WIDTH) ?
        constants.NOTES_MAX_COLUMNS :
        Math.floor(window.innerWidth / constants.NOTES_WIDTH))

      callback = (msg, data) => {
      }
      render() {
        const { notes, language } = this.props;
        if (this.state.pageNotFound) {
          return (<div className="emptyMessage"><span>Empty</span></div>);
        }
        if (notes.loading) {
          return (<Progress/>);
        }
        // To Refresh Child component will receive props
        const lists = [...notes.cards];
        return (
          <div className="notesContainer" >
            <NoteBook notesList={lists} callback={this.callback} coloums={this.state.column} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  notes: PropTypes.object,
  courseId: PropTypes.string,
  language: PropTypes.shape(shapes.language)
};
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you .But ,If I add the fetch then I'm getting error like this  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
        at Function.from (native) .Any inputs on this?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question properly, where exactly are you using fetch

Comment: Like you said ,<NotesContainer.WrappedComponent  notes={notes}> But when I gave like this  <NotesContainer.WrappedComponent  notes={null} the error went off.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(this.props.notes.fetch)` in componentWillMount of component and then run your test with `<NotesContainer.WrappedComponent notes={notes}>`

Comment: Yes I did console log and Still having the same error MyComponent.jsx:104 { [Function: mockConstructor]
    _isMockFunction: true,
    getMockImplementation: [Function],
   mock: [Getter/Setter],
    mockClear: [Function],
    mockReset: [Function],
    mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
    mockReturnValue: [Function],
    mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
    mockImplementation: [Function],
    mockReturnThis: [Function],
    mockRestore: [Function] }
  ● Renders Notes component correctly
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to objecat Function.from (native)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving your component a stub notes.fetch function?

```
Let isFetched = false;
const fakeNotes = {
  fetch: () => isFetched = true
}
```

That way you can test that fetch is called without making a request. I'm not sure, but the test runner is running in node, and I think you may need to require fetch in node, and so the real notes may be trying to use the browser's fetch that does not exist.

I'm not an expert, but I believe it is good practice to use a fakes for side effects/dependencies anyway, unless the test specifically is testing the side effect/dependency.

Comment: Hey @corey ,I'm also in the beginner level for both react and jest.I tried giving like you suggested but I still have the issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

Pass notes as props to your component like `<myComponent.WrappedComponent notes={<here>} />` and also put a check like `this.props.notes && this.props.notes.fetch` so that even if your props aren't passed you don't get an error.